# Adding complete Column Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am trying to add a complete column containing record but whenever I do it shows null.
The data is being coming from firebase.

**To read data**

```dart
   return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: otherStream,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            print('Something went Wrong');
          }
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
  return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: otherStream,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            print('Something went Wrong');
          }
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
  return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: otherStream,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            print('Something went Wrong');
          }
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }

      final controller = ScreenshotController();
          final Stream<QuerySnapshot> otherStream =
              FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('lott').snapshots();
        
                  final List storedocs = [];
                  snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                    Map a = document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                    storedocs.add(a);
                    a['id'] = document.id;
                  }).toList();
    TableCell(
                                child: Center(
                                    child: Text(storedocs[i]['items'].toString(),
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0))),
                              ),
```

Adding a snap

[image: the table]

Any Example would be grateful and helpful thanks

Comment: Are you using `StreamBuilder` and handling snapshot states(loading, error,!hasData)?

Comment: yes I am doing so please review updated

Comment: Also check `snapshot.hasData`